# mysql datetime default 0001-01-01 00:00:00 on update 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table, let's call it employees, that sends data to a web server, whenever this happens a datetime field is updated with a current_timestamp.

Now, when a record changes, I want to reset the datetime field to 0001-01-01 00:00:00 so that it will send the new information again.

Is it possible to do something like

```
DEFAULT 0001-01-01 00:00:00 ON UPDATE 0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

instead of

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: What's the datatype of that column? `datetime` or `timestamp`?

Comment: It is a datetime column

Comment: No, for `on update` only `current_timestamp` and no other values are allowed. You can use a trigger for that. Another option would be to add an `exported_at` column and set it to `current_timestamp` when you export it, and compare that to your `on update current_timestamp` column. If they are different, they were changed and have to be exported.

Comment: OK, I don't really want to use a trigger, your second option sounds promising though, I'll give it a try, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on update` only supports `current_timestamp`; no other value is allowed. See [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> Use of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is specific to TIMESTAMP and DATETIME. The DEFAULT clause also can be used to specify a constant (nonautomatic) default value; for example, DEFAULT 0 or DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00'.

You can either use an `after update` trigger, but the common solution is to use another column and set the value to `current_timestamp` on export and compare that to the latest update:

```sql
create table tablename (
   ... 
   updated_at datetime(6) default current_timestamp(6) 
                          on update current_timestamp(6),
   exported_at datetime(6) default '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
)
```

To get all rows that needs to be exported, use

```sql
select * from tablename where exported_at <> updated_at for update;
```

To mark something as updated after an export, you then use

```sql
update tablename set exported_at = current_timestamp(6);
```

(Everything inside a transaction of course)

Thanks to @Lightness Races in Orbit for pointing out that it's not obvious why to use `datetime(6)` instead of `datetime`: per default, mysql uses `datetime` with second precision. That is usually not a problem - but for this application of detecting changes it would miss updates that were applied within 1 second of the export, and thus would have a slightly different effect than "resetting the column on every update to a value that marks that update". This only works for mysql 5.6.4 and above. Prior to that, use a trigger if you need that precision.

Comment: What's this `(6)` you keep using? Is it _"In very old versions of MySQL (prior to 4.1), the TIMESTAMP data type supported a display width, which was silently ignored beginning with MySQL 4.1. This is deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and removed altogether in MySQL 5.5."_? If so, why are you using it?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You are right, but mysql wouldn't be mysql, if it wouldn't reintroduce `timestamp(n)`/`datetime(n)` in 5.6.(4), now actually meaning the stored fractional precision (that's usually needed in such a query), see [Fractional Seconds in Time Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html): *"The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. **If omitted, the default precision is 0**. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)"*

Comment: Lol! Well, okay - now the problem is you're changing the semantics of the OP's timestamps without explaining or pointing it out in the answer. I'd stick with the original type used by the OP, unless the solution to the problem requires you not to...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I added a remark to explain it, I didn't give it much thought. Actually,  `datetime(6)` is used to NOT change the original idea (of automatically and without triggers setting the value on every update to something that marks that it has been updated), because otherwise it won't mark updates within 1 second of the export.